# UIContainerView stops receiving touch after changing frame

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicontainerview

UIContainerView to display a view controller:

[image]

Now I am tying to make it full screen when user tap full screen button with this code :

```
@IBAction func fullscreen(_ sender: Any) {
        view.goFullscreen()
    }

extension CGAffineTransform {

    static let ninetyDegreeRotation = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2))
}

extension UIView {

    var fullScreenAnimationDuration: TimeInterval {
        return 0.15
    }

    func minimizeToFrame(_ frame: CGRect) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: fullScreenAnimationDuration) {
            self.layer.setAffineTransform(.identity)
            self.frame = frame
        }
    }


    func goFullscreen() {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: fullScreenAnimationDuration) {
            self.layer.setAffineTransform(.ninetyDegreeRotation)
            self.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds

        }
    }
}
```

Making view full screen works fine but when viewcontroller is full screen the view stop receiving touch. This happens when I add constraints to the view controller, but when I remove it it works fine. Why this happens and how can I able to both set constraint and receiving touch?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately gesture recognizers ignore your transform. So you will need to apply the transform to the touch points manually. They are a number of ways to do this, such as by applying the recognizer to the superview, applying the inverse transform to the point, then checking if its inside the bounds of the target view.

Comment: @JoshHomann thanks ! Can you show me some code ?

Comment: I’m on a train. I’ll add code when I get home. Basically the issue is your transform only affects your apparent position on the screen, not your actual bounds. That’s why you should really use the transform for transitory things like animations and use constraints to make permanent size / position changes. In this case I would consider animating the change in constraints here with layoutifneeded instead of using the transform.

Comment: @JoshHomann Hello , did you get home ? I really need to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Here is a playground illustrating how you can apply the transform to detected touch point in the superview:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let redView = UIView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(redView)
        redView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        redView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
        redView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        redView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: redView.superview!.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        redView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: redView.superview!.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        redView.backgroundColor = .red
        redView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi / 2)
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tap))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }

    @objc private func tap(tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let point = tapGestureRecognizer.location(in: redView).applying(redView.transform)
        if redView.bounds.applying(redView.transform).contains(point) {
            print ("You tapped inside")
        } else {
            print("You tapped outside)")
        }
    }
}

let v = ViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = v.view
```